# How to check if the canvas element exists in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to hide the contents of id="root" when the page does not have the canvas element. And I want to show the contents of id="root" when the page has the canvas element. Here is my script:-

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("root").style.display = "none";
  console.log("root = " + document.getElementById("root"));
  let canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
  console.log("canvas = " + canvas);
  let containsCanvas = document.getElementById("root").contains(canvas);

  let inter = setInterval( function() {
    containsCanvas = document.getElementById("root").contains(canvas);
    console.log("contains Canvas = " + containsCanvas);
    if (containsCanvas) {
      document.getElementById("root").style.display = "block";
      clearInterval(inter);
    }
  }, 100)
</script>
```

But this code is not working. I have written this script in the index.html of a react project. The `console.log("contains Canvas = " + containsCanvas);` always shows `false`.

When I inspect, I see that the canvas element is present. But `console.log("canvas = " + canvas);` is showing `undefined`.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It looks like `document.getElementsByTagName` doesnt work for canvas tags

Use an id on the canvas and `document.getElementById`

Comment: How and when is the canvas element meant to appear? Your code suggests a misunderstanding of how React works.

Comment: the canvas element appears dynamically so can't use an id directly